# Django - Pass related object as variable in user_passes_test mixin

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to restrict instances of an object to be viewable only to users referenced by that object via a OneToOneField. I’m using the “user_passes_test” mixin on a DetailView to compare request.user to the user in the OnetoOne relationship. I got some help on django irc which led me to unsuccessfully try and implement get_object, but I’m still stuck (I'm new to Django & Python).

**the Model:**

```
class Event(models.Model):     
    client = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

**the View:**

```
class EventDetail(UserPassesTestMixin, DetailView):
    model = Event

    def test_func(self):
        if self.request.user == self.model.client:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

*User is being referenced in its own app, as User(AbstractUser)*

Comment: How are you using this `test_func` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `DetailView` then you can implement the `get_queryset` method in the view:

```
class EventDetail(DetailView):
    model = Event

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(DetalView, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(client=self.request.user)
```

This would make sure that the `Event` objects are restricted to the user as a client only.

I am not sure what URL are you using to access the Event and why there is just `OneToOne` relation between `Event` and `User`. But if it is a `OneToOne` relation then the `queryset` after this implementation will contain only one object. (which might or might not be the primary key using which you are accessing this event).

Comment: I'm using a OneToOne over a ForeignKey because there will always only ever be 1 event affiliated with 1 user.

Comment: (i didn't realize hitting enter saved the comment!)

- url is calling Event object with pk, for example: http://localhost:8000/events/3/

- So I'm still unsure how to use the output of get_queryset in the test function.

Comment: I see now that your solution replaces the test function and it works perfectly! But I was using the test function so I could also provide an if / else condition that allows a user marked as "staff" to view the object as well. Using your solution how would one have the function check and allow if the user is staff?

Comment: Do you mean that either the user which is logged in and related to the event or any user who is a staff can see this object?

Comment: Yes exactly - your solution with the added if /else check for is_staff seems to be working fine (unless there is some reason why it's no good!)

Comment: It looks good. Just that it is not mentioned in the original post above. So there was no way for me to know that is also a requirement.

Comment: So for future reference, if we were to use "user_passes_test" function, how would we compare request.user to the user that is referenced via the "client" field on the Event model, (the way I was originally trying) ?

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it, I think it took me writing it out to realize I could just put an if / else condition on the queryset like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super(DetailView, self).get_queryset()
    if self.request.user.is_staff:
        return queryset
    else:
        return queryset.filter(client=self.request.user)
```

Thank you AKS!